# Am I building a correct way of organizing characters so I can count them?

Tags: c++

The code is supposed to be able to count the characters in total then count each time they appear within a text file. I tried building a struct that makes an array which is an integer and char array at the same time so that I can have the counting in the same place as my array. But now I am stuck. I've looked online a lot but cannot find what I need to help me. Anyone got some advice? Also in the code if you see anything that should be changed I appreciate the tips! I am newer at c++ so go easy on me please.

Structs, multiple arrays, searching internet for answers

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

struct letters {
    int count;
    char letter;
};

constexpr int SIZE = 10000;

std::string fileName, word;
int count = 0, charCount = 0;
int Alphabet[26];
letters chars[];

void getFileName(std::string& fileName);
int countWords(int& count, std::string& fileName, std::string word);
int countChar(int& charCount, std::string& fileName, letters chars[]);
void sortChars(letters chars[SIZE], int SIZE);

int main()
{
    getFileName(fileName);
    countWords(count, fileName, word);
    countChar(charCount, fileName, chars);
    sortChars(chars, SIZE);
    return 0;
}

void getFileName(std::string& fileName)
{
    std::cout << "Please enter the name of the file followed by the type (ex: text.txt) : " << std::endl;
    std::getline(std::cin, fileName);
}

int countWords(int& count, std::string& fileName, std::string word)
{
    count = 0;
    std::ifstream infile(fileName);
    while (infile >> word) {
        count++;
    }
    std::cout << count << std::endl;
    return count;
}

int countChar(int& charCount, std::string& fileName, letters chars[])
{
    std::ifstream infile(fileName);
    while (infile >> chars->letter) {
        count++;
    }

    std::cout << charCount;
    return charCount;
}

void sortChars(letters chars[SIZE], int SIZE)
{
    int i = 0;
    std::ifstream infile(fileName);
    while (infile >> chars[i].letter) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= chars->count; i++) {
            if (infile == chars[i].letter) {
                chars[i].count++;
            }
        }
    }
}

void printCount()
{
    std::cout << count << std::endl;
    std::cout << charCount << std::endl;
    std::ifstream infile(fileName);
}
```

The struct should count the number of times `'A'` or `'a'`, should be able to convert to one case, but I can do this after it counts one or the other. My tester file is in all lowercase so that would be a good place to start.

Comment: Big hint: stop using global variables.

Comment: Carefully define what you want each function to do. Then write the function. Then test the function to make sure it does what you wan it to do. Based on what `sortChars` does, I don't think `countChar` does exactly what you want it to do. That said, I think you are trying to make `countChar` do too much.

Comment: Ok, I will def try and change those out. Thank you!

Comment: Taking a closer look at `int countChar(int& charCount, std::string& fileName, letters chars[])`, `charCount` is passed in, and then returned unchanged. There isn't much to be gained from this. The `count` variable is incremented, but doesn't do anything else. The `chars` parameter is oddly used. `infile >> chars->letter` just keeps writing to the same letter over and over. Go over each line of the function. Understand what it does. Ask yourself does it do what I need it to do? Do I need it at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even bigger hint, use a [`std::unordered_map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) to count the characters:

```
#include <cstdlib>        // EXIT_FAILURE
#include <cctype>         // std::isupper(), std::tolower()
#include <string>         // std::string<>, std::getline()
#include <unordered_map>  // std::unordered_map<>
#include <iostream>       // std::ifstream
#include <fstream>        // std::cout, std::cerr

int main()
{
    std::string file_name;
    if (!std::getline(std::cin, file_name)) {
        std::cerr << "Input error. :(\n\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    std::ifstream is{ file_name };
    if (!is.is_open()) {
        std::cerr << "Couldn't open \"" << file_name << "\" for reading. :(\n\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    std::size_t num_words = 0;
    std::unordered_map<char, std::size_t> char_counts;
    for (std::string word; is >> word; ++num_words) {
        for (auto ch : word) {
            if (std::isupper(ch))
                ch = std::tolower(ch);
            ++char_counts[ch];
        }
    }

    for (auto const &count : char_counts)
        std::cout << "'" << count.first << "': " << count.second << '\n';   
    std::cout << "Number of words: " << num_words << "\n\n";
}  // when control reaches the end of main() without encountering a return-statement
   // it has the same effect as return 0;
```

If you insist on splitting that few lines of code up into functions:

```
#include <cstdlib>        // EXIT_FAILURE
#include <cctype>         // std::isupper(), std::tolower()
#include <string>         // std::string<>, std::getline()
#include <unordered_map>  // std::unordered_map<>
#include <iostream>       // std::ifstream
#include <fstream>        // std::cout, std::cerr

std::string get_file_name()
{
    std::cout << "Filename: ";
    std::string file_name;
    if (!std::getline(std::cin, file_name))
        std::cerr << "Input error. :(\n\n";
    return file_name;
}

std::ifstream open_file(std::string file_name)
{
    std::ifstream file{ file_name };
    if (!file.is_open())
        std::cerr << "Couldn't open \"" << file_name << "\" for reading. :(\n\n";
    return file;
}

std::size_t get_file_stats(std::istream &is, std::unordered_map<char, std::size_t> &char_counts)
{
    std::size_t num_words = 0;
    for (std::string word; is >> word; ++num_words) {
        for (auto ch : word) {
            if (std::isupper(ch))
                ch = std::tolower(ch);
            ++char_counts[ch];
        }
    }
    return num_words;
}

int main()
{
    std::string file_name{ get_file_name() };
    if (!file_name.length())
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    std::ifstream is{ open_file(file_name) };
    if (!is.is_open())
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    std::unordered_map<char, std::size_t> counts;
    std::cout << "Number of words: " << get_file_stats(is, counts) << "\n\n";

    for (auto const &count : counts)
        std::cout << "'" << count.first << "': " << count.second << '\n';
}
```